# All reflection methods accessing constructor of class generated through ASM throw NoClassDefFoundError if class references primitive type

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am writing an application in which reflected Method objects with specific signatures are unwrapped to regular INVOKEVIRTUAL calls in classes generated through ASM so that those methods can be repeatedly invoked in a more performance-conscious manner. Methods to be unwrapped will always have a specific return type and first parameter, but can have any given number of other parameters of any type past that point.

I have defined two classes to do this, `InvokerProxy` and `NewInvokerProxyFactory`.

```
public interface InvokerProxy {
    ExitCode execute(IODescriptor io, Object... args);
}
```

```
public final class NewInvokerProxyFactory {

    private static final String GENERATED_CLASS_NAME = "InvokerProxy";

    private static final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<MethodVisitor>> UNBOXING_ACTIONS;

    private static final AtomicInteger NEXT_ID = new AtomicInteger();

    private NewInvokerProxyFactory() {}

    public static InvokerProxy makeProxy(Method backingMethod, Object methodParent) {
        String proxyCanonicalName = makeUniqueName(InvokerProxyFactory.class.getPackage(), backingMethod);
        String proxyJvmName = proxyCanonicalName.replace(".", "/");

        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
        FieldVisitor fv;
        MethodVisitor mv;

        cw.visit(V1_8, ACC_PUBLIC | ACC_SUPER, proxyJvmName, null, Type.getInternalName(Object.class), new String[]{Type.getInternalName(InvokerProxy.class)});

        cw.visitSource("<dynamic>", null);

        {
            fv = cw.visitField(ACC_PRIVATE + ACC_FINAL, "parent", Type.getDescriptor(Object.class), null, null);
            fv.visitEnd();
        }

        {
            mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", Type.getMethodDescriptor(Type.VOID_TYPE, Type.getType(Object.class)), null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, Type.getInternalName(Object.class), "<init>", "()V", false);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTFIELD, proxyJvmName, "parent", Type.getDescriptor(Object.class));
            mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
            mv.visitMaxs(2, 2);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }

        {
            mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_VARARGS, "execute", Type.getMethodDescriptor(Type.getType(ExitCode.class), Type.getType(IODescriptor.class), Type.getType(Object[].class)), null, null);
            mv.visitCode();

            mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitFieldInsn(GETFIELD, proxyJvmName, "parent", Type.getDescriptor(Object.class));
            mv.visitTypeInsn(CHECKCAST, Type.getInternalName(methodParent.getClass()));
            mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1);

            Class<?>[] paramTypes = backingMethod.getParameterTypes();
            for (int i = 1; i < paramTypes.length; i++) {
                mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 2);
                mv.visitLdcInsn(i-1);
                mv.visitInsn(AALOAD);
                mv.visitTypeInsn(CHECKCAST, Type.getInternalName(paramTypes[i]));
                if (paramTypes[i].isPrimitive()) {
                    UNBOXING_ACTIONS.get(paramTypes[i]).accept(mv);
                }
            }

            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, Type.getInternalName(methodParent.getClass()), backingMethod.getName(), Type.getMethodDescriptor(backingMethod), false);
            mv.visitInsn(ARETURN);
            mv.visitMaxs(backingMethod.getParameterTypes().length + 2, 3);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }
        cw.visitEnd();

        try {
            return (InvokerProxy) SystemClassLoader.defineClass(proxyCanonicalName, cw.toByteArray()).getDeclaredConstructor(Object.class).newInstance(methodParent);
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new InvokerProxyGenerationException("Exception creating invoker proxy for method '" + backingMethod + "'", e);
        }
    }

    private static String makeUniqueName(Package parentPackage, Method method) {
        return String.format("%s.%s_%d", parentPackage.getName(), GENERATED_CLASS_NAME, NEXT_ID.getAndIncrement());
    }

    static {
        Map<Class<?>, Consumer<MethodVisitor>> actions = new HashMap<>();
        actions.put(Byte.TYPE, mv -> mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, Type.getInternalName(Byte.class), "byteValue", "()B", false));
        actions.put(Short.TYPE, mv -> mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, Type.getInternalName(Short.class), "shortValue", "()S", false));
        actions.put(Integer.TYPE, mv -> mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, Type.getInternalName(Integer.class), "intValue", "()I", false));
        actions.put(Long.TYPE, mv -> mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, Type.getInternalName(Long.class), "longValue", "()J", false));
        actions.put(Float.TYPE, mv -> mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, Type.getInternalName(Float.class), "floatValue", "()F", false));
        actions.put(Double.TYPE, mv -> mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, Type.getInternalName(Double.class), "doubleValue", "()D", false));
        actions.put(Boolean.TYPE, mv -> mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, Type.getInternalName(Boolean.class), "booleanValue", "()Z", false));
        actions.put(Character.TYPE, mv -> mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, Type.getInternalName(Character.class), "charValue", "()C", false));
        UNBOXING_ACTIONS = actions;
    }
}
```

Through testing I have discovered that if the method being unwrapped by the InvokerProxyFactory has any primitive parameters (int, char, float, etc..), attempting to look up a constructor for that class through any of the normally provided reflection methods (`Class.getConstructors`, `Class.getDeclaredConstructor`, etc...) will result in a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` citing the first primitive type found in the method signature as its message. The exception is apparently caused by `URLClassLoader.findClass`, where a `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown with the same message.

Apparently this issue going even beyond constructors since even `Unsafe.allocateInstance` throws this same exception when creating an instance of the generated class. There are also absolutely no issues looking up constructors or creating instances when the unwrapped method does not have any primitive parameters.

Comment: Could you post the stack track of the exception, and the generated classfile if possible? Also, is there a reason you can't just use invokedynamic? It's already designed to do what you're doing, but more efficiently.

Comment: Interesting project, but I'm pretty sure the reflection implementation and hotspot compiler is already doing this. I would be interested in benchmarks once you have this running.

Comment: @Jörn Horstmann: I’m quite confident that a direct `MethodHandle` which doesn’t need varargs boxing is potentially more efficient or at least on par compared to this. And if the number of parameters is fixed, `LambdaMetaFactory` may do the same.

Comment: @Holger I've actually written a little tool to generate that kind of thing. See https://gist.github.com/foundry27/25879129939b0043077b5fe2e46aeec2
The reason I'm not using this here is because the method signatures aren't fixed in this case, so I can't create a one-off SAM interface to use with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code looks very suspicious

```
mv.visitTypeInsn(CHECKCAST, Type.getInternalName(paramTypes[i]));
```

This code is called unconditionally, even if `paramTypes[i]` is a primitive type. However, the [ASM documentation](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getInternalName-java.lang.Class-) says that `getInternalName` can only be called for a real object or array type. ASM probably just generates a bogus class name when given a primitive, hence the error.

> ```
> public static String getInternalName(Class c)
> ```
>
> Returns the internal
> name of the given class. The internal name of a class is its fully
> qualified name, as returned by Class.getName(), where '.' are replaced
> by '/'.
>
> Parameters:
>
> c - **an object or array class**.
>
> Returns:
>
> the internal name of the given class.

Also, note that the CHECKCAST instruction is not valid for primitive types anyway.

Comment: The result is quite predictable. `Class.getName()` returns the name of the primitive type, e.g. `int`, replacing `.` by `/` has no effect and using that as internal name causes the JVM to search for a class with that name, e.g. a class having the name `int` (unless the verifier rejects it beforehand because a reference type `int` can’t be passed to a method expecting the primitive type `int`—what is checked first is implementation specific).

Comment: @holger That's what I figured, since that would be the most naive implementation, but I didn't want to make assumptions without looking at the implementation source.

Comment: Well, that’s also how the documentation describes it. Since there is no other behavior mentioned, there is no reason to assume special behavior (the only assumable special behavior would be throwing an exception, which obviously didn’t happen here).

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, it was helpful in diagnosing the issue. I guess this is what comes from not looking closely enough at the documentation, haha